# how to select last n month before the last date in field mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question with mysql.
I have a table like records and records have a field registered_date which contains the dates. I want to select last n months but not before the current date. I must select the last date that registered_date contains.

registered_date

- 2015-05-30
- 2015-05-29
- 2015-05-28
- 2015-05-27
- ...

and we are in july. The last date is 2015-05-30. I want to select last 3 months before the 2015-05-30.

I tried to like these:

```
 .... where registered_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

and

```
registered_Date between now() - interval 30 day and now()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the table's structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for that data?

Comment: @Mureinik is this clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the biggest date and then select three months before that:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select max(registered_date) as maxrd from table t) m
where t.registered_date >= maxrd - interval 3 month;
```

Comment: Just remember if your last date is 2015-05-30 this will also give you 2015-02-28 while the >= applies the interval -3 months. Just saying, so you (Yusuf) know what data is coming out.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind . . . That is a worthwhile point.  The OP states "three months before 2015-05-30", but doesn't specify exactly what this means.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. Just wanted to make him know what data he can get out. Nice query though, It is the answer. +1 As you do the cross join. Better than selecting max date for each row.

Comment: I conerted this solution into my problem and i encountered a problem which '#1267 - Illegal mix of collations'. I solved this problem with using binary after 'where' @GordonLinoff

Comment: @YusufÇakmak . . . I'm not sure where collations are coming into play.  I was not aware they applied to dates.  Further, I don't think there is anything in the query that would change the collation of anything.  So, I'm confused where your error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE registered_date >= now()-interval 3 month;
```